# Array element checking in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Currently implementing a favourite function to my application which is based on quotes. I would like to perform a check for if the user has already saved an element to an array. If they have, I would change a favour button to unfavour button.
import UIKit

```
class DreamViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var liketext: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var QuoteImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var DreamLabel: UILabel!
    var counter = 1

    var factIndex = 0

    let dreamFact = Dream()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        DreamLabel.text = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func LeftSwipe() {
        factIndex--
        var number = dreamFact.dreamArray.count - 1
        if (factIndex < 0){
            self.factIndex = number

        }
        DreamLabel.text = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
        if counter == 1 {

            counter = 36

        } else {

            self.counter--

        }

        QuoteImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).jpg")

    }
@IBAction func RightSwipe() {
        factIndex++
        if factIndex >= dreamFact.dreamArray.count {
            self.factIndex = 0
        }
        DreamLabel.text = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
    if counter == 36 {

    counter = 1

    } else {

    self.counter++

    }
    QuoteImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).jpg")
}
    struct Constants {
        static let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        static let fqKey = "FavoriteQuotes"
        static let like = "Like"
        static let unlike = "Unlike"
    }
    class DreamViewController {




        var favouriteQuotesArray = Constants.defaults.objectForKey(Constants.fqKey) as? [String] ?? [String]() {
            didSet {
                Constants.defaults.setObject(favouriteQuotesArray, forKey: Constants.fqKey)
            }



    }

         @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton! {

            didSet {
                let favourite = dreamArray[factIndex]
                if let foundIndex = find(favouriteQuotesArray, favourite) {
                    likeButton.setTitle(Constants.unlike, forState: .Normal)
                }
                else {
                    likeButton.setTitle(Constants.like, forState: .Normal)
                }
            }



        }

        @IBAction func likeButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        }

        }
}
```

**The dependency on upon the text which is unreliable because if the user reopens the app, the element would still be saved instead of starting out with the default unlike**. If the element is found in the array. **How would I perform a search inside my favouriteQuotesArray if the element exists like**:

```
if elementfound statement {

button.settitle(unlike)
removearrayatindex statement.

} else {
button.settitle(like)
makeQuoteFavourite()
}
```

**How would the array checking statement look like?**
P.S If you can please give tips on building the delete class?
**Update:**

```
 var favouriteQuotesArray: [String] = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("thekey") as! [String]

    func makeQuoteFavourite() {
        if favouriteQuotesArray == nil {
            favouriteQuotesArray = []
        }
        let currentQuote = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
        favouriteQuotesArray.append(currentQuote)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(favouriteQuotesArray, forKey: "thekey")
    }
    @IBAction func likeButton() {

        if contains(favouriteQuotesArray, dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]) {
        liketext.setTitle("Unlike", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
```

Comment: first find the index of the element that you want to remove from the array ...and then call method arr.removeAtIndex(index)..this will work

Comment: @anish parajuli in reference to my NSUserdefaults statement?

Comment: what type is this currentQuote ???

Comment: @anish parajuli a string array I believe

Comment: its string..so find the string in the array on the button click and do as... if let temp = find(favouriteQuotesArray,"value"){favouriteQuotesArray.removeAtIndex(temp)} and then again save it into userDefaults

Comment: @anishparajuli answer more formally in answer section so if it works i could give you credit?

Comment: first check...this is not well tested code....just written from windows. :)

Comment: @anishparajuli doesn't work very well

Comment: thats the basic logic..yo have to implement in your code...as required

Answer (score 3):

Do it this way; some cleaner coding techniques to cut through the rubble included.

The declaration of favouriteQuotesArray is a gold star one liner. Got it all?

```
import UIKit

struct Constants {
    static let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    static let fqKey = "FavoriteQuotes"
    static let like = "Like"
    static let unlike = "Unlike"
}

class Page2ViewController: UIViewController {
    var dreamArray = [String]() // place holder so class compiles
    var factIndex = 0           // place holder so class compiles

    var favouriteQuotesArray = Constants.defaults.objectForKey(Constants.fqKey) as? [String] ?? [String]() {
        didSet {
            Constants.defaults.setObject(favouriteQuotesArray, forKey: Constants.fqKey)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            let favourite = dreamArray[factIndex]
            if let foundIndex = find(favouriteQuotesArray, favourite) {
                likeButton.setTitle(Constants.unlike, forState: .Normal)
            }
            else {
                likeButton.setTitle(Constants.like, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func likeButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        let favourite = dreamArray[factIndex]
        if let foundIndex = find(favouriteQuotesArray, favourite) {
            sender.setTitle(Constants.like, forState: .Normal)
            favouriteQuotesArray.removeAtIndex(foundIndex)
        }
        else {
            sender.setTitle(Constants.unlike, forState: .Normal)
            favouriteQuotesArray.append(favourite)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do i add this to my view controller?

Comment: It is a complete View Controller. You should be able to adapt it to yours by filling in the gaps. Try to understand the whole code to see what it replaces in yours.

Comment: If that's too confusing to do, modify your question with your entire ViewController.swift file. I'm finding this happens frequently with Xcode / UI problems. Never enough context.

Comment: can you send me a chat request I believe this question is better resolved there?

Comment: Great detailed answer but it does have some issues while attaching to my code, hope we can get in contact to make things easier for me and you. Gave an upvote but needs further communication for it to be an accepted answer

Comment: The code is fine; I've tested your project in my environment. We don't have a clear description of what exactly is going wrong at this point. It may be most efficient to have an experienced programmer help in person. Your goals are ambitious for your current skill level and it's now more a question of grounding in fundamentals than a particular technical question.

Comment: can you revisit the chat?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let currentQuote = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
if find(favouriteQuotesArray!, currentQuote) != nil {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: @NewBeginnings sorry, I didn't quite understand where you needed to put the check. Could you give a little more context?

Comment: I need to see if a string existed in an array or not.

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer to reflect that. If this doesn't work, replace the currentQuote variable with the string you need to find. Good luck with your app :)

Answer (score 1):

The better and quick way to find out an element in an array is:

```
if contains(yourFavArray, stringStatement){
  //Contains you can write your logic
}
```

Change your favouriteArray as below:

```
var favouriteQuotesArray: [String] = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("thekey") as! [String]
```

Edited:

```
 if let foundIndex = find(favouriteQuotesArray, dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]) {
     sender.setTitle(Constants.like, forState: .Normal)
     favouriteQuotesArray.removeAtIndex(foundIndex)
 }
```

Comment: Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '([String]?, String)' on line   if contains(favouriteQuotesArray,dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex])

Comment: Cannot assign to the result of this expression

Comment: I see if contains(favouriteQuotesArray, dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]) with error. Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '([String]?, String)'

Comment: removes the error I mentioned tho but it generates Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String]' and 'nil' here func makeQuoteFavourite() {
        if favouriteQuotesArray == nil {
            favouriteQuotesArray = []
        }

Comment: @NewBeginnings Can you please update your code with the latest changes?

Comment: look at the update code, the error is still there Binary Operator ---

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84866/discussion-between-newbeginnings-and-sohil-r-memon).

Comment: if let foundIndex = find(favouriteQuotesArray, dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]) {
            sender.setTitle(Constants.unlike, forState: .Normal)
            favouriteQuotesArray.removeAtIndex this statement makes everything "unlike" in my viewcontroller, why is this?